# python: regex doesn't grab the last part of a text

Tags: python, regex, subprocess

Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32.

I got this code to test ...
It parses the output from a proces bs1770gain and I need all the little pieces of it...I tried with subprocess.call, the popen and pipe, check_output... I get the results but then strange things happen with the regex... hittin a wall...
So...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import subprocess
#from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

#p = Popen(['bs1770gain','C:\\Users\\myrthe\\Music\\', '-file '],stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
#output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
#inputtexts = p.returncode
regex = re.compile(ur'(\s{2,2}\[\d+\/\d+\].*?|\[ALBUM\].*?)(?=\s{2,2}\[\d+\/\d+\]|\s{2,2}\[ALBUM\]:|done\.$)', re.DOTALL | re.UNICODE)
#inputtext = open(r'C:\Users\myrthe\Music\2014 - 1989\result.txt')
#print(inputtext.read())
#inputtexts = subprocess.call(['bs1770gain','C:\\Users\\myrthe\\Music\\'])
output =  subprocess.check_output(['bs1770gain','C:\\Users\\myrthe\\Music\\'])
print (output)
results = re.findall(regex, output)
for r in results:
    print('=======result====')
    print(r)

print (output)
```

this is what I get back from output... some small strange things but everything is there as we see after the regex

```
analyzing "2014 - 1989" ...
  [1/19] "01. Welcome To New York.mp3":
      integrated:  -7.9 LUFS / -15.1 LU
  [2/19] "02. Blank Spac        4%
      integrated:  -8.3 LUFS / -14.7 LU
  [3/19] "03. Style.mp
      integrated:  -7.5 LUFS / -15.5 LU
  [4/19] "04. Out Of The Woods.mp
      integrated:  -9.1 LUFS / -13.9 LU
  [5/19] "05. All You Had To Do Was Stay.mp3":
      integrated:  -7.8 LUFS / -15.2 LU
  [6/19] "06. Shake It Of        2%
      integrated:  -8.2 LUFS / -14.8 LU
  [7/19] "07. I Wish You Would.mp3":
      integrated:  -8.4 LUFS / -14.6 LU
  [8/19] "08. Bad Blood.mp3":
      integrated:  -8.8 LUFS / -14.2 LU
  [9/19] "09. Wildest Dreams.mp3"
      integrated:  -9.9 LUFS / -13.1 LU
  [10/19] "10. How You Get The Girl.mp3":
      integrated:  -8.4 LUFS / -14.6 LU
  [11/19] "11. This Love.mp
      integrated:  -9.0 LUFS / -14.0 LU
  [12/19] "12. I Know Places.mp
      integrated:  -7.8 LUFS / -15.2 LU
  [13/19] "13. Clean.mp3":
      integrated:  -9.9 LUFS / -13.1 LU
  [14/19] "14. Wonderland.mp3":
      integrated:  -8.2 LUFS / -14.8 LU
  [15/19] "15. You Are In Love.mp
      integrated:  -10.7 LUFS / -12.3 LU
  [16/19] "16. New Romantics.
      integrated:  -7.8 LUFS / -15.2 LU
  [17/19] "17. I Know Places (Voice Memo        1%
      integrated:  -19.4 LUFS / -3.6 LU
  [18/19] "18. I Wish You Would (Voice Memo).mp3":
      integrated:  -18.4 LUFS / -4.6 LU
  [19/19] "19. Blank Space (Voice Memo        4%
      integrated:  -17.9 LUFS / -5.1 LU
  [ALBUM]:
      integrated:  -9.2 LUFS / -13.8 LU
done.
```

and this is the last part of the results after regex. Everything is there it seems...

```
=======result====
  [16/19] "16. New Romantics.mp3":
      integrated:  -7.8 LUFS / -15.2 LU

=======result====
  [17/19] "17. I Know Places (Voice Memo).mp3":
      integrated:  -19.4 LUFS / -3.6 LU

=======result====
  [18/19] "18. I Wish You Would (Voice Memo).mp3":
      integrated:  -18.4 LUFS / -4.6 LU

=======result====
  [19/19] "19. Blank Space (Voice Memo).mp3":
      integrated:  -17.9 LUFS / -5.1 LU
```

Except..And there is the problem, I do not for the life of me get that [ALBUM] in my results. I tried the regex on onlinecheckers with the output to a text file, tried the regex on this machine with the output in a textfile... It gives what I want. I use the same regex on my linux machine and I get the results I want. But straight this way... I just don't get that last [ALBUM].
So if any of you people can shed some light on this or put me on the right path, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Without input string it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Well, the output string is what bs1770gain puts out. It prints that on the console or to a file. So that output is ...well... my input ...to put it that way

Comment: it is because there is a linefeed after `done.` so the `$` anchor makes the pattern fail.

Comment: That popped in my head at 5 in the morning in my sleep. Thanks Casimir et Hippolyte. So I changed the  `$` in `\s` and it works...So SOLVED